# Boilerpipe Starter issue

Tags: java, exception, text-extraction, boilerpipe

I am new to boilerpipe. I tried to run sample code given on their website:

```
  import java.net.URL;
  import de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ArticleExtractor;
  import de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.DefaultExtractor;

    public class TESTURLBOILERPIPE {
        public static void main(String[] arges) throws Exception 

    {

         final URL url = new URL(
                    "http://www.l3s.de/web/page11g.do?sp=page11g&link=ln104g&stu1g.LanguageISOCtxParam=en");
         ArticleExtractor ae = new ArticleExtractor();
            System.out.println(ae.INSTANCE.getText(url));
    }
}
```

I have added all the required jar files to the class path, however I get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: usage: supply url to fetch
at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:45)
at org.jsoup.examples.HtmlToPlainText.main(HtmlToPlainText.java:26)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Boilerpipe, but are you sure you are trying to run the correct Java class? The stack trace looks like you are trying to run `HtmlToPlainText` (without arguments, thus the exception), but from the code you posted I think you would like to run your `TESTURLBOILERPIPE` class.

Comment: import java.net.URL;
  import de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ArticleExtractor;
  import de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.DefaultExtractor;

    public class TESTURLBOILERPIPE {
        public static void main(String[] arges) throws Exception 

    {

         final URL url = new URL(
                    "http://www.l3s.de/web/page11g.do?sp=page11g&link=ln104g&stu1g.LanguageISOCtxParam=en");
         
            System.out.println(ArticleExtractor .INSTANCE.getText(url));
    }
}

Comment: @Zahran How are you trying to start your `TESTURLBOILERPIPE` class? Are you using Eclispe, NetBeans or some other IDE? Or have you tried to start it using the command line (e.g. `java TESTURLBOILERPIPE`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a python wrapper. It takes care of all the dependencies, though you might have to install jpype manually (that source code is on sourceforge).

https://github.com/misja/python-boilerpipe